# How do I translate this Perl regular expression into Java?

Tags: java, regex, perl

How would you translate this Perl regex into Java?

```
/pattern/i
```

While compiles, it does not match "PattErn" for me, it fails

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/pattern/i");
Matcher m = p.matcher("PattErn");

System.out.println(m.matches()); // prints "false"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How would you translate this Perl regex into Java?
>
> ```
> /pattern/i
> ```

You can't.

There are a lot of reasons for this.  Here are a few:

- Java doesn't support as expressive a regex language as Perl does.  It lacks grapheme support (like `\X)` and full property support (like `\p{Sentence_Break=SContinue}`), is missing Unicode named characters, doesn't have a `(?|...|...|)` branch reset operator, doesn’t have named capture groups or a logical `\x{...}` escape before Java 7, has no recursive regexes, etc etc etc. I could write a book on what Java is missing here: Get used to going back to a **very** primitive and awkward to use regex engine compared with what you’re used to.
- Another even worse problem is because you have lookalike *faux amis* like `\w` and and `\b` and `\s`, and even `\p{alpha}` and `\p{lower}`, which behave differently in Java compared with Perl; in some cases the Java versions are completely unusable and buggy.  That’s because Perl follows [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) but before Java 7, Java did not.  You **must** add the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASSES` flag from Java 7 to get these to stop being broken. If you can’t use Java 7, give up now, because Java had many many many other Unicode bugs before Java 7 and it just isn’t worth the pain of dealing with them.
- Java handles linebreaks via `^` and `$` and `.`, but Perl expects Unicode linebreaks to be `\R`. You should look at `UNIX_LINES` to understand what is going on there.
- Java does not by default apply any Unicode casefolding whatsoever. Make sure to add the `UNICODE_CASE` flag to your compilation.  Otherwise you won’t get things like the various Greek sigmas all matching one another.
- Finally, it is different because *at best* Java only does simple casefolding, while Perl always does full casefolding. That means that you won’t get `\xDF` to match "SS" case insensitively in Java, and similar related issues.

In summary, the closest you can get is to compile with the flags

```
 CASE_INSENSITIVE | UNICODE_CASE | UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASSES
```

which is equivalent to an embedded `"(?iuU)"` in the pattern string.

And remember that match in Java doesn’t mean match, perversely enough.

---

## EDIT

And here’s the rest of the story...

> While compiles, it does not match "PattErn" for me, it fails
>
> ```
>    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/pattern/i");
>    Matcher m = p.matcher("PattErn");
>    System.out.println(m.matches()); // prints "false"
> ```

You shouldn’t have slashes around the pattern.

The best you can do is to translate

```
$line = "I have your PaTTerN right here";
if ($line =~ /pattern/i) {
    print "matched.\n";
}
```

this way

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String line     = "I have your PaTTerN right here";
String pattern  = "pattern";      
Pattern regcomp = Pattern.compile(pattern, CASE_INSENSITIVE
                                        | UNICODE_CASE
                // comment next line out for legacy Java \b\w\s breakage 
                                        | UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASSES  
                                );    
Matcher regexec = regcomp.matcher(line);    
if (regexec.find()) {
    System.out.println("matched");
}
```

There, see how much easier that isn’t? :)

Comment: +1 for "There, see how much easier that isn’t? :)".  Oh, and for a rocking answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Perl equivalent of:

```
/pattern/i
```

in Java would be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)pattern");
```

Or simply do:

```
System.out.println("PattErn".matches("(?i)pattern"));
```

Note that `"string".matches("pattern")` validates the pattern against the *entire* input string. In other words, the following would return false:

```
"foo pattern bar".matches("pattern")
```

Comment: Is there a web site that lists common Perl-> Java rules of translation as you described?

Comment: Not that I know of. Java's regex patterns look pretty much like Perl's, only without the delimiters.

Comment: @mac This has all you need to know about Java regex: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html Including a list of the flags like CASE_INSENSITIVE and some examples

Comment: @Bart: They make look pretty much like Perl’s — if you don’t look too closely — but they don’t act that way.  See my answer.

Comment: @tchrist, yeah, Perl's regex implementation is far more powerful. By my remark: _"looking the same"_, I meant on a syntax level: Java supports much of the PCRE functionality. And I always see your answers (wrt regex, that is: always very informative!).

Answer (score 1):

Java regex do not have delimiters, and use a separate argument for modifies:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("pattern", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Perl does full Unicode casefolding on case-insensitive matches. Therefore that is not equivalent.